# Magento 2 - time picker on backend (xml form)

Tags: magento2, adminform, datepicker

I need to to have only time picked in the form. I have a field

```
<field name="open">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tuesday</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">somesource</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">open</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="timeOnly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

hours and minuts scroll bars doesnt work properly for me. How to make the datepicked to show only time? Or how to make a field that saves time only

Comment: The default input (date) does not support this format, so you should create own input-element.

Comment: You need something similar to [this](https://gyazo.com/b55c0c0caf8f46e8bcefe5610fecfb9a)  ?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau do you know how to implement that one?

Comment: @magefms Sure, just use an inbound jQuery slider plugin. If you need an example - just send me a link to your question and I'll post an answer with my code.

Comment: here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269454/how-to-implement-time-picker-in-magento-2-admin-system-xml

Comment: @magefms I posted the answer, but it taken from another part of magento - regular form (not from the config section). I've rewriten a code to make it work, but some aspects need modifications. I hope my example will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Ciemin, try this code:

```
<field name="opening_time">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Opening time</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">opening_time</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                <item name="timeOnly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Result:
[image]